# Understanding ES6 to ES5 code as transpiled by Babel

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

Babel transpiles the following ES6 code

```
test(){
    var list = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
    var [ a, , b ] = list
    [ b, a ] = [ a, b ]
  }
```

into this

```
function test() {
      var list = [1, 2, 3];

      var _list = list[(b, a)] = [a, b];

      var _list2 = _slicedToArray(_list, 3);

      var a = _list2[0];
      var b = _list2[2];
    }
```

I can't understand what exactly is happening with this line of code

```
var _list = list[(b, a)] = [a, b];
```

Specifically, I am clueless with list[(b, a)]. Any help is much appreciated?

Comment: I'd bet that if you played around a bit in your JavaScript console you'd figure it out.

Comment: I did experiment a bit in the console by evaluating something like (1,2,10,9) and found that value returned is always the value form the last expression. I did that to know what would (a,b) evaluate to in list[(b,a)]. But I knew nothing about what the comma operator is and how it works. Without knowing what it is called in the language, I had no way of validating my findings. And also the semi colon insertion part that  @loganfsmyth explained probably would never have struck me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that

```
var [ a, , b ] = list
[ b, a ] = [ a, b ]
```

is the same as

```
var [ a, , b ] = list[ b, a ] = [ a, b ]
```

because automatic semicolon insertion does not apply to this situation. The same case applies to this ES5 example:

```
var list = [1, 2, 3]
var value = list
[1]
console.log(value);
```

If you run this code, it will log `2`, not `[1, 2, 3]` because the index is applied to the previous line, rather than treated as an array on the following line.

Automatic semicolon insertion generally applies in cases where the parser encounters a syntax error, goes back a step, and tries after inserting a semicolon.

In both of these cases, the content of the following line is perfectly valid as part of the previous line, so it is treated as such with no automatic semicolon.

In your example, `list[a, b]` is parsed as accessing an index using the result of comma-operator operation, which will essentially evaluate to `list[b]`. The comma operator processes a list of expressions one at a time, and then finally evaluates to the result of the last expression.